# Proper way to use a config file?

Tags: php, kohana

I just started using a PHP framework, Kohana (V2.3.4) and I am trying to set up a config file for each of my controllers.

I never used a framework before, so obviously Kohana is new to me. I was wondering how I should set up my controllers to read my config file.

For example, I have an article controller and a config file for that controller. I have 3 ways of loading config settings

```
// config/article.php
$config = array(
    'display_limit'         => 25, // limit of articles to list
    'comment_display_limit' => 20, // limit of comments to list for each article
    // other things
);
```

Should I

A) Load everything into an array of settings

```
// set a config array
class article_controller extends controller{

    public $config = array();

    function __construct(){
        $this->config = Kohana::config('article');
    }       
}
```

B) Load and set each setting as its own property

```
// set each config as a property
class article_controller extends controller{

    public $display_limit;
    public $comment_display_limit;

    function __construct(){
        $config = Kohana::config('article');

        foreach ($config as $key => $value){
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

C) Load each setting only when needed

```
// load config settings only when needed
class article_controller extends controller{

    function __construct(){}

    // list all articles
    function show_all(){
        $display_limit = Kohana::config('article.display_limit');
    }

    // list article, with all comments
    function show($id = 0){
        $comment_display)limit = Kohana::config('article.comment_display_limit');
    }
}
```

Note: Kohana::config() returns an array of items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading a group of configuration items for a controller, store them in class member (`$this->config`), if you are reading a single configuration item; read it individually.

Answer (score 0):

I think first method (A) should be fine, it has lesser code and serves the purpose fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have site wide stuff that you want access to from "anywhere", another way of doing it may be to put something like:

```
Kohana::$config->attach(new Kohana_Config_File('global'));
```

in bootstrap.php. Then create global.php in the application/config directory with something like:

```
return (array ('MyFirstVar' => 'Is One',
               'MySecondVar' => 'Is Two'));
```

And then when you need it from your code:

```
Kohana::config ('global.MyFirstVar');
```

But I suppose all of this comes down to where and how you want to use it.